# Adjusting the voiceover of a collection from page x of y

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiaccessibility

I have a table view with a collection view in one cell. The collection view presents several cells, and it has `UIPageControl` to allow swipe between the collection cells.

My problem is that the voiceover over the page control says:

> page x of y ...

and I want it to say:

> image x of y ...

The table view cell that contains the collection is implementing `UIScrollViewAccessibilityDelegate` and returns the required String in its `accessibilityScrollStatusForScrollView` method.

However, this method is not called and the voiceover doesn't use it.

Answer (score 2):

The UIScrollViewAccessibilityDelegate protocol needs to be implemented on the delegate of the scroll view. So whatever object is the delegate of the collection view, needs to implement the protocol. (I'm guessing your table view cell is not the delegate of the collection view it contains).